# Tensorflow's tf.get_default_session() returns a None in a ROS Subscriber callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, ros, rospy

I am trying to run a small neural-network in a ROS Subscriber callback. I can get the outputs through `self.sess.run()`, if `self.sess` is defined as a class member. But if I try to get the session inside the ROS Subscriber callback, using `tf.get_default_session()` it returns a `None`.

Is there any way that I can get the session instance inside the ROS Callback, without declaring it as a class member?